# Use Constants inside of Doctrine Attributes for types

Tags: attributes, doctrine, constants

I have Entity and have some fields related to DateTime, for example one of them

```
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'enter_date', type: 'date', nullable: true)]
    #[Type('DateTime<"Y-m-d">')]
    private ?DateTimeInterface $enterDate = null;
```

And I want to use value `Y-m-d` from constant class, is it possible to rewrite code to something like that ?

```
final class Constant {
    final public const DATETIME = 'Y-m-d';
}
```

and

```
#[ORM\Column(name: 'enter_date', type: 'date', nullable: true)]
#[Type('DateTime<"@Constant::DATETIME_FORMAT">')]
private ?DateTimeInterface $enterDate = null;
```